# Mercurial: Track repo with .hg dir and work-tree in separate directories

Tags: mercurial

I have often used [this approach](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/dotfiles) to dot file management in git, where I create a bare git repo "~/.dotfiles" and us  `$HOME` as a work tree. With the shell alias `config` I can then add dot files from the home dir quickly (as in `config add`, `config commit`

```
alias config='git --git-dir=$HOME/.dotfiles/ --work-tree=$HOME'
```

I wonder if a similar setup is possible in mercurial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular repository for that[^bare] and clone it with the share extension. Creating a new home dir as one-liner:

```
hg --config extensions.share= share $HOME/.dotfiles $HOME
```

For more information see `hg help share`. For information how to ignore changes to untracked files, see `hg help hgignore`.

[^bare]: If it is important for you to have no files in the .dotfiles, just `hg update null` in `~/.dotfiles`. That’s the root of the repository (before anything got added). Mercurial needs no special bare state.